# Is there a simply way of Doc to Docx in apps script without authorization for non-google users when they run the script after emailsent being invoked?

Tags: google-apps-script, authorization

Simply trying to convert doc to docx. Success with my google account is saved authorization header are there on browser. However since apps script can't reach this info, we are not squared.

```
var options = {
        muteHttpExceptions: false,
        }
      };
      var blb = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=' + docurl + '&exportFormat=docx',
        options).getBlob();
```

There should be new and easy way, if I mutehttperrors, I can create one docx with the error sayıng the file can't be found. The file is there but there is this error:

```
Error   
Exception: Request failed for https://docs.google.com returned code 404.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please post a [minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that we can help you.

Comment: Thanks @jhoepken, editing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are the owner of the Google Document and/or you have the permission for reading or writing to the Google Document, you can use the following script.

#### Modified script:

```
var docurl = "###"; // Please set the Document ID which is not URL.
var options = {
  muteHttpExceptions: true,
  headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() }
};
var blb = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=' + docurl + '&exportFormat=docx', options).getBlob();

DriveApp.createFile(blb); // When you use this script, the converted DOCX is created as a file on the root folder of your Google Drive.
```

- In this case, you can use the access token by `ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()`. When `DriveApp` is used in your script, I think that the scope can be used for using the endpoint.

#### Note:

- From the error message of `Request failed for https://docs.google.com returned code 404.`, in your script, I'm worry that `docurl` might be not the Google Document ID. In that case, an error occurs. In that case, please use the Google Document ID. It's like `###` of `https://docs.google.com/document/d/###/edit`.

#### Reference:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)

Comment: Thanks for great explanation, however this script will be open to anyone and for those who run it should be able to reach created docs each time script run and convert from doc to docx

Comment: @Bitdom8 Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `however this script will be open to anyone and for those who run it should be able to reach created docs each time script run and convert from doc to docx`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Thank you again for pointing out. Each time the script runs, it will create a new template doc on google drive folder on my account which should be accessible to anyone. Then this file could be easily converted from doc to docx

Comment: @Bitdom8 Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about the relationship between my answer and `Each time the script runs, it will create a new template doc on google drive folder on my account which should be accessible to anyone. Then this file could be easily converted from doc to docx`. My answer is for exporting Document as DOCX data. So, I cannot understand about your current situation. Can I ask you about the detail of it? By this, I would like to think of the solution. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: @Bitdom8 Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. I had thought that your question is to export Google Document as DOCX data. Is my understanding correct? Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `I have a form which triggers the script and creates a doc. This doc should be docx and be emailed to the user who fills the google forms.`. So I'm worry whether I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Hi again @Tanaike pleasure to hear you speaking in any language:) I have a form which triggers the script and creates a doc. This doc should be docx and be emailed to the user who fills the google forms. Please see above. Have removed unrelavant code but can't share the irrelevant code. 

Basicly the doc which created should be exported but non-google users when the event is triggered, even cognito tabs.

Comment: @Bitdom8 Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, from your updated question, I cannot understand about `Basicly the doc which created should be exported but non-google users when the event is triggered, even cognito tabs.`. In this case, I think that my sample script can be used. So, can I ask you about your current issue using my sample script?

Comment: @Bitdom8 I would like to confirm my understanding for your question again. You want to export Google Document as DOCX data. Is my understanding correct? In this case, I think that my answer can be used. And also, you want to send an email including the converted DOCX data as the attachment file. For this, you want the sample script. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I have the script already, when the script is triggered after google form fill, the users get pdf along with doc file already. Can the script send users docx along with  pdf doc? Thanks. Script itself need to convert it even for users incognito mod

Comment: Your script is working but for google users only, wanted it to work for nongoogle users Request failed for https://docs.google.com returned code 404 the 404 occurs when nongoogle users try to run the script. Then It can't translate doc to docx

Comment: @Bitdom8 Thank you for replying. About `Can the script send users docx along with pdf doc?`, I think that DOCX file and PDF file can be sent as the attachment files. About `but for google users only, wanted it to work for nongoogle users Request failed for docs.google.com returned code 404 the 404 occurs when nongoogle users try to run the script.`, I cannot understand about your situation. So, in this case, how about posting it as new question by including more information? Because in your this question is different from it. If I misunderstood your replying, I apologize.

Comment: Have edited the Q, by "authorization" I meant invoking function within the script, otherwise the code of mine was working. However you have shed insightful light on this. Thanks

Comment: @Bitdom8 Thank you for replying and updating your question. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From your replying, I understood that you cannot post your new question as new question. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your updated question. Can you provide the detail of your question? By this, I would like to try to understand your updated question.

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike, Need to allow users to fill a form on their end. Later on script can simply convert generated doc on my gdrive (which is should be allowed by the script we have created thanks to you). But right now, script doesn't allow this

Comment: @Bitdom8 Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, for your updated question, I cannot image about `Need to allow users to fill a form on their end. Later on script can simply convert generated doc on my gdrive (which is should be allowed by the script we have created thanks to you). But right now, script doesn't allow this`. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal? By this, I would like to try to understand them and to support you. I apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike. For instance, users can download the generated doc file by simple line of code without need to enter my account. Is this possible?

Comment: @Bitdom8 Thank you for replying. About your replying, unfortunately, I cannot answer for this. Because I cannot still understand about your current situation from your question. I think that from your question, it is required to know more information for understanding it. This is due to my poor English skill. I apologize for this again. So, in order to correctly understand about your current situation, can you provide the detail flow for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to try to understand it.

Comment: @Bitdom8 I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Now, I cannot still understand about your updated question. I could understand about your 1st question before you updated and could propose the answer. But, about your updated question, I cannot understand it. This is due to my poor English skill. I apologize for this. Can you provide more information for your updated question? I deeply apologize for this again.

Comment: Hİ @Tanaike, it is because of my English maybe. I will try to improve the question more later on if I can understand what it is causing it. Now I can't really provide more details because, I can't understand the cause of it. Thanks

Comment: @Bitdom8 Thank you for replying. In the current stage, your 1st question was resolved. But your new question by your updating is still not resolved because I cannot understand about your new question. I have to apologize for this situation. In this case, can I ask you about what I can do your situation?